# Ternary operator behavior

Tags: python, ternary-operator

I recently started using ternary operator but I encountered a case where I needed to use multiple ternary operator in the same line, but they didn't seem to work as I expected.

Can someone please give a explanation why those line give different result.

```
x = 1 if True else 2 + 3 if False else 4  # x = 1, I expected 5
x = (1 if True else 2) + (3 if False else 4)  # x = 5
```

If I add parentheses I get the expected result, but I don't understand what the parentheses change.

And if I rotated the addition, without the parentheses, I get the correct value.

```
3 if False else 4 + 1 if True else 2  # x = 5
```

However, I get wrong result if the second ternary operator is False:

```
3 if False else 4 + 1 if False else 2  # x = 5 # x = 2 ???
```

Is it because you shouldn't multiple ternary operator in the same  line, or is their an other reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Think of it as applying parentheses around each of the three inputs:

```
x = (1) if (True) else ((2 + 3) if (False) else (4))
```

Here you can clearly see that `x` will equal `1` and that your `2 + 3...` won't be run.

When you 'rotated' it:

```
(3) if (False) else ((4 + 1) if (True) else (2))
```

So now the `3` doesn't run because the condition is `False` so you get the `4 +...` term instead

and in your last case

```
(3) if (False) else ((4 + 1) if (False) else (2))
```

it returns `2` because the `(4+1)` is the true condition for your second condition (which is `False`)

If you're still confused, write it out as a regular `if` statement:

```
x = (1) if (True) else ((2 + 3) if (False) else (4))
```

becomes

```
if True:
    x = 1
else:
    if False:
        x = 2 + 3
    else:
        x = 4
```

Answer (score 6):

The reason is [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Conditional expressions have the lowest-but-one precedence, only lambda expression is lower. Therefore, the expression

```
1 if True else 2 + 3 if False else 4
```

is evaluated as

```
1 if True else ((2 + 3) if False else 4)
```

which returns 1.

Answer (score 4):

```
x = 1 if True else 2 + 3 if False else 4
```

is the same as

```
x = (1) if (True) else (2 + 3 if False else 4)
```

(Unless you want to play around with different constructs just for fun, I really don't recommend writing code like this.)